Start Flutter app on device boot (Autostart)
I would like to start my Flutter app as soon as the Android phone starts.
I have tried Autostart packages (all outdated), Flutter Background Service and BootReceiver with AndroidManifest but nothing worked. Please help me, thanks!
I did everything as described here: How to start your Android app at boot in Flutter?
There seems to be a problem with the import, but I don't know why.



@the-only-smart-boy I added some screenshots but I cannot find your comment anymore.

Check this doc:https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts
